# Is it possible to choose a git stash when they're described by the date stashed?

Tags: git, git-stash

I'm able to list git stashes by date with

```
git stash list --date=local
```

but how do I select a revision without getting

```
fatal: Needed a single revision
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to put quotation marks around the date:

```
git stash show -p stash@{Friday Smarch 13 13:13:13 2013}
```

won't work, while

```
git stash show -p stash@{"Friday Smarch 13 13:13:13 2013"}
```

works. (With the date given, it actually gave me the most recent stash, rather than saying it was invalid!)

Comment: For future readers, this is just an issue of the shell requiring escaping of a single argument with embedded spaces. Either quoting the whole thing (`"stash@{Friday Smarch 13 13:13:13 2013}"`) or individually escaping each space (`stash@{Friday\ Smarch\ 13\ 13:13:13\ 2013}`) would work just as well.