# "Too many revisions" git message

Tags: git, powershell, git-stash

On git version 1.7.9.5, when trying

```
git stash show -p stash@{"Friday Smarch 13 13:13:13 2013"}
```

(from [Is it possible to choose a git stash when they're described by the date stashed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3243231/is-it-possible-to-choose-a-git-stash-when-theyre-described-by-the-date-stashed) )

I get the error message

```
Too many revisions specified: stash@{Friday Smarch 13 13:13:13 2013}
```

I also get the same error message when trying the following

```
git stash show "stash@{Friday Smarch 13 13:13:13 2013}"
git stash show -p stash@{Friday\ Smarch\ 13\ 13:13:13\ 2013}
```

I don't think escaping is the cause. If I do

```
git stash show -p stash@{Friday\ Smarch\ 13\ 13:13:13 2013}
```

Then I get a different error message:

```
fatal: ambiguous argument 'stash@{Friday Smarch 13 13:13:13': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions
```

By contrast, doing

```
git stash show -p stash@{42}
```

Works.

What does the error message mean, and what should I do?

Comment: I tried simulating the your situation.  I am also getting same error as you had got.  However, 
git stash show -p --date=local, 
did work for me, without any errors.  
I do not know what the error mean!

Comment: `git stash` simply hands the argument to `git rev-parse`.  What does: `git rev-parse --no-flags --symbolic stash@{"Friday Smarch 13 13:13:13 2013"}` print?  (Also, I'm curious, why "Smarch"?)

Comment: @torek Smarch is the 13th month of the year. From Treehouse of Horror VI, The Simpsons.

Comment: @torek,  git rev-parse --no-flags --symbolic stash@{"Friday Smarch 13 13:13:13 2013"} gives the output  :  
stash@{Friday Smarch 13 13:13:13 2013}

Comment: @user1562655: That should give the "unknown revision" error, which makes sense (there's no rev associated with the nonexistent date with the lousy weather) ... it's the "too many revisions" one that does not.  ... Aha, *my* `git rev-parse` gives that error, not that output!  (Even if I build a 1.7.9.5 version)

Comment: Ah, never mind previous comment, I've figured out how to trigger the problem.  Interesting, it's because `git rev-parse` is ... overly generous and decides that if there is *some* stash@{anything} it can just print that as "close enough".  But it has white space in it, so the `stash` script assumes that this resolved to multiple stash entries, and gives you the weird error.

Answer (score 127):

This does not answer the OP's specific situation but I don't have enough reputation to add this as a comment... This page is one of the top search results for the error message `Too many revisions specified`

If you are using Posh Git or some other powershell command line then you get the above error message when you enter a command like

```
git stash show -p stash@{2}
```

Powershell doesn't like the curly braces.

```
git stash show -p stash@'{'2'}'
```

should do the trick.

Similarly:

```
git stash show -p "stash@{2}"
```

also avoids the error.

Comment: power shell problem. Thanks (y)

Comment: PowerShell also allows backticks for escaping if you want to save a couple characters : `git stash show -p stash@\`{0\`}`

Comment: or  git stash show <TAB>
it might take a moment but it will cycle through your stash list, inserting the properly formatted <stash> (as noted by @MariuszPawelski and @user1007074)

Comment: i used `git stash show -p stash@'{'0'}'` and it worked but now I can't get out of whatever mode my terminal is now in; `ctrl+c` won't work.

Comment: Just type the `q` key

Comment: Worked for me `git stash show -p "stash@{2}" ` using Windows (powershell)